# How to display a stack panel after some delay on button hover in WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf

I have one button, on hovering mouse on that button for two seconds, i want open the stack panel.

xaml code:

```
<StackPanel x:Name="spPinDetailsPopup" Height="200" Width="240" Visibility="Hidden">
     <!--it contains label control which have text to display-->
</StackPanel>
<Button x:Name="btnDisplayPopUp" MouseEnter="DisplayPopUpOnMouseEnter"/>
```

CS code :

```
void DisplayPopUpOnMouseEnter(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    spPinDetailsPopup.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
}
```

I have used the stack panel as a pop up which displays the control information.

**Current Result :** Stack panel is displayed immediately.

**Expected Result :**
**Stack panel should only be open when we put mouse cursor on button for more than 2 seconds.**
Is there any solution ?

Comment: yes, try and we'll help.

Comment: as you've written it above, without a good [mcve] showing what you've tried, the question is far too broad. If/when you fix your question so it's good enough to be worth answering, you will want to make sure you are also specific about what you mean by "open the stack panel". A `StackPanel` object isn't "closeable", so it's not clear what it would mean to "open" one.

Comment: Thanks guys for your response, i have updated the question :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not use `ToolTip`?

```
    <Button ToolTip="Some Text" ToolTipService.InitialShowDelay="2000"/>
```

As `ToolTip` is an `object`, you can configure the layout to whatever you like, not just some text.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/controls/tooltip-overview

Comment: @Leblanc, User requirement is that display short info in tooltip and detailed info in the popup, so i have used stack panel as a popup.

Answer (score 0):

**Solution :**

I created one DispatcherTimer object at global level to controlling the time interval to open the popup.

```
private static DispatcherTimer _popUpOpeningTimer = new DispatcherTimer();

void DisplayPopUpOnMouseEnter(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    // if we do not have DispatcherTimer set then only initialize it 
    if (_popUpOpeningTimer == null)
    {
          _popUpOpeningTimer = new DispatcherTimer();
    }
    else // this means that dispatcher timer is already initialized, so do nothing
    {
         // do nothing
    }
    // stop the timer if it is already set so that we can start new timer
    _popUpOpeningTimer.Stop();

    _popUpOpeningTimer.Interval = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 1);

    _popUpOpeningTimer.Tick += new EventHandler((senderObject, eventArguments) => DisplayPopUp(senderObject, eventArguments, btnDisplayPopUp));

    // start the timer for opening the details popup
    _popUpOpeningTimer.Start();  
}

private void DisplayPopUp(object sender, EventArgs e, Button button)
{
    if(button.IsMouseOver)
    {
         spPinDetailsPopup.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
    }
    else
    {
         // do nothing
    }
}
```